# how to add the green folder as the pic in github

Tags: github, tortoisegit

[image: the green folder]

what i want to know it is that how to how to add the green folder as the pic in github?

and then if i use TortoiseGit ,how do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those green folder are **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** ([special git entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297899/checkout-past-git-submodule-commit/2300638#2300638))

When you clone that repo, you need a:

```
git submodule update --init
```

That will update those folder in your local working tree.
(or "`TortoiseGit > Submodule update.`")

Starting [April, 30th 2013](http://developer.github.com/changes/2013-04-30-improved-submodule-support-in-repository-contents-api/), when you view a repository with a submodule on github.com, you get useful links and information for the submodule.

[image: submodule]

Comment: @caizZZz that picture comes directly from GitHub blog post, so you would have to ask them that question ;) mailto:support@github.com